# How can I append the values to the nested keys inside the object in the model through formdata

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, multipartform-data, form-data

I have a modal on server side having object like

```
  location: {
    lat: {
      type: Number
    },
    lng: {
      type: Number
    }
  },
```

Now I want to append the values to lat and lng inside the location object. How can I achieve that? I know we can append the values to location like

formData.append("location", value);

Comment: Hello your question is not clear, The formdata used when sending data to server from react-native so you want to send it in form data or server side you need to have location object updated in response?

Comment: Yes I want to update the location object keys i.e. lat and lng. I'm sending data from my react native app through formdata to be saved in mongo db.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help, I did it in a simpler way and I believe it works for all hypotheses, please test.

If it doesn't fit your use case, please comment so I can edit my answer.

### Full Code:

```js
const parses = []

const fKey = key => ((function until(value, comp = value) {
    const result = value.replace(/\.([A-z0-9]*)(\.|$)/, '[$1]$2')

    return comp !== result ? until(result, value) : result
})(key))

function populateFormData(values, form = new FormData(), base = '') {
    Object.keys(values).forEach(key => {
        const value = values[key]

        if (typeof value == 'string' ||
            typeof value == 'number' ||
            typeof value == 'boolean' ||
            value instanceof File ||
            value instanceof Blob)
        {
            form.append(fKey(`${base}${key}`), value)
            parses.push({
                key: `${fKey(`${base}${key}`)}`,
                value
            })
        } 
        else if (typeof value == 'object') 
        {
            populateFormData(value, form, `${base}${key}.`)
        }
    })
    
    return form;
}

populateFormData({
    title: 'Lucas',
    text: 'Is good :)',
    preview: {
        p_title: 'I am a P title',
        p_text: 'I am a P text',
        test: {
            example: 2,
            my: {
                obj: [
                    'eba',
                    {
                        hyper: 'text'
                    },
                    123
                ],
                yes: true
            }
        }
    }
})

console.log(parses)
```